# Twitter Bootstrap: Content Appears When Button is Clicked, But Content Should Show on 'Hover' - What's Wrong Please?

Tags: jquery

Using the W3C Bootstrap popover tutorial I got the below Code.  Using Visual Studio the webpage runs fine; however, the content "It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!" should show when the button is hovered over (as in the 1st demo here: http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/popover-tutorial.php)

But, it doesn't - you have to click the button - why is hover not working?

I have these three files in my project root:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>  
<script src="js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>  
<script src="js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
```

and I have tried adding a trigger like this:

```
{ $("#example").popover({trigger: 'hover'});,
```

But, that did not work either.

What am I missing please?

Comment: Could you show the code for your button?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="example" class="btn large primary" rel="popover">hover for popover</a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var img = '<img src="" />';

$("#example").popover({ title: 'Look! A bird!', content: img });​​​
```

---

Example exposed in: http://jsfiddle.net/weuWk/

Now adapt to your problem!!

Comment: Doing it now - thanks.  Work comittments and my b'day meant this is the first time that I've been near my PC sinec.  I'll get back.

Comment: Hello.  I have the very same issue: The button has to be clicked on to make the text appear.  Just hovering over it does not work??

Comment: something is wrong in your code, this works perfectly with me, check your code!
call the javascript in the end of the document HTML before </body>

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it: Nowhere in the Twitter Bootstrap or W3C popover tutorial does it mention that I should have accessed the 'js/bootstrap-popover.js' file and change the click trigger to hover to get hover to work.

I opened JS/bootstrap-popover.js sort of by accident and noticed this code:

```
   $.fn.popover.defaults = $.extend({}, $.fn.tooltip.defaults, {
    placement: 'right',
     trigger: 'click'
```

So, I changed the trigger to hover:

```
trigger: 'hover'
```